# Ruby regex avoid matching a group

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-group

I have this code running inside a buffer (used to unescape a JS string in Ruby):

```
  elsif hex_substring =~ /^\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}/
    hex_substring.scan(/^((\\u[\da-fA-F]{4}){1,})/) do |match|
      hex_byte = match[0]
      buffer    << JSON.load(%Q("#{hex_byte}"))
      hex_index += hex_byte.length
    end
  ...
```

I have a concern that the `scan()` is matching a bit too much:

```
hex_substring.scan(/^((\\u[\da-fA-F]{4}){1,})/)
# => [["\\ud83c\\udfec", "\\udfec"]]
```

I am using only `"\\ud83c\\udfec"`, not `"\\udfec"`.

Is there a way in Ruby or in regex to grab only the first part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a single grouping construct here, the one to match 1 or more occurrences of four hex chars, and omit the inner capturing group that resulted in an extra item in the resulting array:

```
.scan(/^(?:\\u[\da-fA-F]{4})+/)
```

Note that `+` is a simpler and shorter way to write `{1,}` (one or more occurrences).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group (what it matches won't be added to the final `scan` result):

  - `\\u` - a `\u` substring
  - `[\da-fA-F]{4}` - four hex chars
- `)+` - 1 or more occurrences (of the group pattern sequence).